# How to fix the error of "could not start avd" while running emulator in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator, avd-manager

Before this error I got a different error. Which was **"unable to locate adb"**. I tried online video to fix this problem but the video didn't fix them. I tried multiple thing to fix it like removing **"platform-tools" and reinstalling a fresh one from sdk manager, I also tried going to my project file to android->app->src->main->java->io.flutter.plugins then I doubled clicked **"GeneratedPluginRegistrant"** then in the top right corner it gave an option setup sdk I clicked that then in android it seted up my sdk. But still that didn't work. Then after a while I closed android studio for 5-7 hours then it gave me the error of **"could not start avd"** what should I do here a Image of what happened and it also says a device is not found in the top left corner please tell me how to fix this error.[image]

Comment: Try creating a new emulator and running it.

Comment: I tried it, still said could not start avd

Comment: I removed intel HAXM and downloaded a fresh one from sdk manager it got rid of the problem of unable to start avd. Now it tell me the problem of unable to locate adb